# What happened to the MSDN C++ Language Reference?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, reference, documentation

Around 2007 I remember installing Visual Studio (I don't remember the exact version), which was shipped on CDs in those days.  There were some extra CDs in our pack, called I think "MSDN C++ Language Reference" which if you installed them gave you inline language guides - we were using C/C++ then.  With these installed you could highlight something in the code and hit a key (possibly F1 I don't remember exactly) and it would bring up a side panel with a great summary of the language feature.  This worked for the core language and the standard library.  This was a brilliantly fast way of checking, for example, all the methods of std::set.

I just had an extensive look for something equivalent for modern versions of Visual Studio (currently I'm running 2019, probably will upgrade to 2022 soon), and I ended up only with web-based language guides for C++ from Microsoft.

Can anyone confirm if this documentation has been deprecated or if it is available in some form?

For rapid lookup of language features it was a very handy feature, one which I think could be very nicely brought back - it could show for example which modern C++ features are supported by which compilers.  For me it would be awesome to have a well-structured and up-to-date language guide built into the IDE.

Thanks!

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Developer_Network

Comment: I believe that documentation is now available online.  Not sure if it is directly "fast accessible" from Visual Studio anymore.  Not sure what you can do if you are working offline. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/c-cpp-language-and-standard-libraries?view=msvc-170

Comment: Thanks @Eljay, Yes, I came across that page in my searches.  I think it would take longer to navigate through that and find the specific thing one was looking for, than to just go to cppreference.com (for example), but even this would be slower than offline, IDE-based documentation.

Comment: As far as I know these days there is only the online documentation. I agree it was convenient to have the reference "embedded" in Visual Studio (and even before when it was called something like Visual C++).

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/Cppreference:Archives

Comment: A problem with the local version was that it soon became much faster to Google MS's online documentation than to start the local help engine. So "rapid lookup" means go online! And F1 still works.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, we get Language Reference in several ways:

1. Select the code (usually variables, functions and classes), then hit F1, you will jump to the corresponding document.

[image]

2. Select the code and press the right mouse button, you can select Peek definition to view the definition.

[image]

3. Search the code you need directly in [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/docs/).

[image]